# How to create and set compound structure for ceiling type?

Tags: revit-api

I am trying to set compound structure for ceiling type and wall type for wall type it working good but when I tried to set for ceiling type then it gives me exception that
 "Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.ArgumentException: 'Input compound structure has wrong End Cap condition for this element type. Parameter name: src Structure'"

CompoundStructure cStructure = CompoundStructure.CreateSingleLayerCompoundStructure(materialFunctionAssignment, width, materialId1);

```
                        cStructure.SetLayers(clayer);

                        ceilingType.SetCompoundStructure(cStructure);
```

Is there any other way to set compound structure for ceiling type

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I do some changes and using this two method my issue is solve

structure.SetLayers(clayer);
 floorType.SetCompoundStructure(structure);